# Transform double to int multiple of 10

Tags: c++, rounding

I have a list of double being calculated from a formula. One of these double are for example 88.32547. I want to transform them into the nearest integer multiple of 10 and put them in another variable.

In the example double `a = 88.32547` which lead to `int b = 90` or if `double a = -65.32547` leads to `int b = -70`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10*std::round(x/10)
```

You may want to add an int cast :

```
int(10*std::round(x/10))
```

For details, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be something like this

`int a = (round(x / 10.0) * 10)`

Divides by ten (to move the decimal point to the left), rounds off (to get to nearest integer) then multiplies by ten again.

Comment: @charbely Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Divide the number by 10, round to the nearest integer and multiply by 10 again.

Examples:

- 10 × round(88.32547 / 10) = 10 × round(8.832547) = 10 × 9 = 90
- 10 × round(−65.32547 / 10) = 10 × round(−6.532547) = 10 × −7 = −70

For rounding, you may consider using [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

Comment: Shouldn't the first example be 90?

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where I could not use Round I used something like this (I needed something specific with negative integers) :

```
bottomValue = floor(a/10)*10;
topValue    = ceil(a/10)*10;
if(a-bottomValue < topValue-a)
    return bottomValue;
else
    return topValue;
```

If you can use round :

```
roundValue = round(a/10)*10;
return roundValue;
```